# Setting radial gradient with javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to set a radial gradient to a div as background with JS. I want the gradient to start in the middle with something like 0.8 opacity and as it goes further to the edges the opacity becomes 0, creating soft fading effect. I tried a few things, but some didn't work at all and some worked not as good as I hoped for.

The one that worked, but not very good, was when I tried to apply it with many `rgba` definitions and reduce the opacity by 0.1 stop:

```
arrCircleDivs[i].firstChild.style.backgroundImage = 
    '-webkit-radial-gradient(center,rgba('+r+','+g+','+b+',0.8),
    rgba('+r+','+g+','+b+',0.8),rgba('+r+','+g+','+b+',0.8),rgba('+r+','+g+','+b+',0.7),rgba('+r+','+g+','+b+',0.6),rgba('+r+','+g+','+b+',0.5),rgba('+r+','+g+','+b+',0.4),
    rgba('+r+','+g+','+b+',0.3),rgba('+r+','+g+','+b+',0.2),
    rgba('+r+','+g+','+b+',0.1),rgba('+r+','+g+','+b+',0))';
```

And these ones didn't work at all:

```
arrCircleDivs[i].firstChild.style.backgroundImage = '-webkit-radial-gradient
    (center, circle cover, rgba(30,87,153,0.7) 0%,rgba(30,87,153,0) 100%);

arrCircleDivs[i].firstChild.style.backgroundImage = '-webkit-gradient
    (radial, center center, 0px, center center, 100%, color-stop(0%,rgba(30,87,153,0.7)), 
    color-stop(100%,rgba(30,87,153,0)));
```

I got the following error message:

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL`

So is there any way to set such effect with JS?

Comment: JavaScript does not allow unescaped newlines inside quotes.

Comment: There're now line breaks in my code, it's all written in one line. I just made a few here for convenient reading.

Comment: missing a single-quote on second set of code to end the strings (both).

Comment: @rfornal Yup, that too. The first line worked then. Not as good as I hoped for, but that's another issue. Thanks!

Comment: This [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nqe8b9vq/1/) seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

The only way i have found to do this is to use the `element.style=backgroundVar` and in your backgroundVar have it set to the `background:...`

E.G

```
let bg = `background:radial-gradient(circle at 0% 0%, 
                rgba(255,0,0,1), rgba(255,0,0,0) 75%), 
            radial-gradient(circle at 0% 100%, 
                rgba(0,0,255,1), rgba(0,0,255,0) 75%), 
            radial-gradient(circle at 100% 0%, 
                rgba(255,255,0,1), rgba(255,255,0,0) 75%),
            radial-gradient(circle at 100% 100%, 
                rgba(0,255,0,1), rgba(0,255,0,0) 75%);`

        document.getElementById("background").style = bg;
```

Answer (score -1):

You could create it using CSS. You'll want to use all of the browser extension calls to ensure cross-platform consistency.

To create a radial gradient you must also define at least two color stops.

**Example of Radial Gradient:**

[image]

**Radial Gradient Syntax**

```
background: radial-gradient(shape size at position, start-color, ..., last-color);
By default, shape is ellipse, size is farthest-corner, and position is center.
```

Radial Gradient - Evenly Spaced Color Stops (this is default)

**Example**

A radial gradient with evenly spaced color stops:

```
#grad {
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(red, green, blue); /* Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
  background: -o-radial-gradient(red, green, blue); /* For Opera 11.6 to 12.0 */
  background: -moz-radial-gradient(red, green, blue); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
  background: radial-gradient(red, green, blue); /* Standard syntax */
}
```

Comment: As I wrote to a previous answer - I need to do it to a few dozens of divs and change rgb values randomly with every page refresh.

Answer (score -2):

Why even use JS ?

A better approach would be to simply add a class to your 'arrCircleDivs[i].firstChild' , something like .new-gradient-class.

Then On the actual CSS, you use this class to set the gradients you want.

Comment: Because Javascript allows for easier animation in some frameworks, such as Famo.us

Comment: Because I need to set it to a few dozens of divs, where each gradient has its own rgb value. And it changes with every page refresh.